# Google Cloud Task not calling http requests

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have created a google cloud task and the queue keeps retrying and the function is not getting invoked as well.

This is the log from the cloud console.

```
  attemptResponseLog: {
   attemptDuration: "0.133874s"    
   dispatchCount: "19"    
   maxAttempts: 0    
   responseCount: "0"    
   retryTime: "2020-06-21T21:20:18.518655Z"    
   scheduleTime: "2020-06-21T21:20:15.718098Z"    
   status: "UNAVAILABLE"    
   targetAddress: "POST some url"    
   targetType: "HTTP"    
  }
```

Comment: Is the target URL valid? Is the target endpoint protected by a security layer that Cloud Tasks doesn't enforce?

Comment: does your functions has the permission to invoke your functions? can you provide reproducible steps or code snippet for your issue? are there any other related logs that you believe may connected to this issue? please provide those logs and any error that you believe is related

Comment: I'm experiencing the same result, does the status `unavailable` have some specific meaning? I'm using cloud functions to enqueue the task and handle it. Only logs I can find are as above, the function doesn't show any invocations/errors. It requires authentication and the service account email I send with the task has functions invoker and service account user roles. It'd be nice to see some actual 40Xs or something.

Comment: @darnmason did you deploy the function and specify that it can't allow unauthenticated invocations?

Comment: @jdhurst yes. I've been using this function already behind cloud endpoints.

Comment: I had the same problem, and I solved it by creating a service account with these permissions: Cloud Functions Invoker, Cloud Tasks Enqueuer, Service Account User. I was getting 'UNAVAILABLE', and did the above and set the oidcToken on the created task.

Comment: I solved my issue, wasn't actually a service account issue, it was the audience on the generated OIDC token. I was using a Cloud Function as the URL but with a path suffix for internal routing. I had to explicitly set the audience to omit the path. So url was `https://functionHost/functionName/tasks/queueName`, I set the audience in my create task to `https://functionHost/functionName`. Some debugging info would have been really useful in figuring that out!

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by assigning project owner role to the service account

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error, and I must say that the documentation is not clear enough.

**WARNING :** I feel there's a bit of latency for the roles to be taking into account, especially with the ServiceAccountUser one.

I made multiple test, and tried to keep the lowest rights possible, so I did try to remove some... do some test, it works... great, it's not necessary to have this right... came back later, and the thing is broken.

Here is my setup :

I use Cloud Scheduler to trigger a Cloud Function every 15 minutes by posting a message on a queue.
The CloudFunction build a list of tasks to compute stats on MySQL and create the tasks
Another Cloud Function run SQL query to get stats and store the results in FireStore.

I use cloud task so that the load on MySQL is not too heavy.

Below, I use functional names to make it easy to understand.

- TaskCreatorCloudFunction running with *TaskCreatorServiceAccount*

  - *TaskCreatorServiceAccount* requires

    - the "**Cloud Task Enqueuer**" role #1
    - be a ServiceAccountUser on the CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount (see after) #2
    - The Roles needed to do the job(read SQL to get the list of tasks to create, write logs, access secret manager, listen to pubsub as it's triggered by Cloud Scheduler via pubsub)
- TaskImplementationCloudFunction (http) running with *TaskImplementationServiceAccount*

  - *TaskImplementationServiceAccount* has no specific role for CloudTasks, only the one needed to do the job (read SQL, write logs, access secret manager, firestore write)

The TaskQueue is named "compute-stats-on-mysql".

I've created a dedicated ServiceAccount named CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount #3

CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount has the specifics rights for the whole thing to work.

- Cloud Function Invoker #4
- Add CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount as ServiceAccountUser on TaskImplementationServiceAccount #5

To do the last one in the console (script version below), you need to

- go to IAM->Service Account
- check the TaskImplementationServiceAccount
- In the upper right corner, click "Show Info Panel" if it's not already displayed
- click the Add Member
- Paste the full name of the CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount
- Choose Service Account User as role
- Save

You can edit this in the console, but it's better to script it.

```
gcloud tasks queues create compute-stats-on-mysql \
    --max-dispatches-per-second=10 \
    --max-concurrent-dispatches=15 \
    --max-attempts=2 \
    --min-backoff=1s
#3
gcloud iam service-accounts create CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount --description="Service Account for the cloud task compute-stats-on-mysql" --display-name="Service Account for the cloud task compute-stats-on-mysql"
#4
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} --member serviceAccount:CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"

#1
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} --member serviceAccount:TaskCreatorServiceAccount@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role "roles/cloudtasks.enqueuer"

#5
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding TaskImplementationServiceAccount@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member="serviceAccount:CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"  --role "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"

#2
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member="serviceAccount:TaskCreatorServiceAccount@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"  --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

when Creating the Task, you use the CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount in the oidcToken

```
const body  = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)).toString('base64');
  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url,
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail: "CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body,
    },
  };
```

My understanding is that when you run the

```
const [response] = await cloudTasksClient.createTask({parent, task});
```

The Cloud Function (Task Creator) need to Create Task, and act as the "CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount"
And "CloudTaskComputeStatsServiceAccount" need to have the cloud function invoker and act as the target cloud function.

Comment: This definitely is the solution for sending tasks correctly. However, I'm still getting `status: "UNAVAILABLE"` once the task reaches the queue. It seems to be unable to find the private target address (inside the VPC).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's not a service account issue.  It's the OIDC token audience missing.  Seems that for cloud functions this is needed.  I found two references... you can recreate this problem with the OIDC token in the cli by omitting this argument to `gcloud tasks create-http-task`

```
--oidc-token-audience=OIDC_TOKEN_AUDIENCE
    The audience to be used when generating an OpenID Connect token to be 
    included in the request sent to the target when executing the task. 
    If not specified, the URI specified in the target will be used
```

The second reference that popped up, in ruby shows `audience`
https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-tasks/latest/Google/Cloud/Tasks/V2/OidcToken.html

Code using google-cloud-tasks 1.5.0, the tasks object looks like this, where `url_oidc` has just the url to the cloud function (i.e. the trigger url... no url parameters)

```py
# Construct the request body.
    task = {
            'http_request': {  # Specify the type of request.
                'http_method': 'GET',
                'url': url_final,  # The full url path that the task will be sent to.
                'oidc_token': {
                    'service_account_email': service_account_email,
                    'audience': url_oidc
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: How do I get the url_oidc? Couldn't find it in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: In this example calling a cloud function, it's the same as the `url_final` but without any URL parameters.